# Background image isn't showing up. Why?

Tags: html, css

I'm really stuck. I'm a beginner in CSS and i try to work with a background image.

> When i don't use the parameter `no-repeat` everything works well but with `no-repeat` the image don't show up. Is this a size problem?

I've tried to work with `<style></style>` but this also doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated!

```css
 #bg--service {
   background-image: url('http://www.sternwarte-radebeul.de/Images_vstw/fotos/sterngucker.jpg') no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row articles" id="bg--service">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12 article">
      <h1>Treuhand und Finanzen</h1>
      <p>Sie wollen sich auf Ihren Fachbereich konzentrieren, brauchen Unterstützung in Ihren Finanzen, eine Fiskal- oder Steuervertretung oder wollen Ihre Freizeit nicht mit buchhalterischen Fragen belasten?<a href=“#”>Mehr>></a>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to use background property instead of background-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) shorthand notation in the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property, which won't work.

Change

```
background-image: url(../img/sternengucker.jpg) no-repeat;
```

to

```
background: url(../img/sternengucker.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Or use two separate rules like:

```
background-image: url(../img/sternengucker.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

background-image only accept the image property.

If you use the following it will work:

```
background-image: url('../img/sternengucker.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

You can read more about the background image property here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

You can also use the background shorthand:

```
background: url('../img/sternengucker.jpg') no-repeat top left;
```

This link shows more information about the background shorthand:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#bg--service {
    background: url(../img/sternengucker.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

If you want to use `background-image`, then use this:

```
#bg--service {
    background-image: url(../img/sternengucker.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And then read this:

[documentation background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

[documentation background-repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Or whole documentation about background and its properties [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The `background image` and `background-repeat` are sub-properties of the background property so to fix it the `background-image` should be replaced with `background`.

```css
 #bg--service {
   background: url('http://www.sternwarte-radebeul.de/Images_vstw/fotos/sterngucker.jpg') no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row articles" id="bg--service">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12 article">
      <h1>Treuhand und Finanzen</h1>
      <p>Sie wollen sich auf Ihren Fachbereich konzentrieren, brauchen Unterstützung in Ihren Finanzen, eine Fiskal- oder Steuervertretung oder wollen Ihre Freizeit nicht mit buchhalterischen Fragen belasten?<a href=“#”>Mehr>></a>
      </p>
    </div>
```

or you can separate the line in two properties

```css
 #bg--service {
   background-image: url('http://www.sternwarte-radebeul.de/Images_vstw/fotos/sterngucker.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row articles" id="bg--service">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12 article">
      <h1>Treuhand und Finanzen</h1>
      <p>Sie wollen sich auf Ihren Fachbereich konzentrieren, brauchen Unterstützung in Ihren Finanzen, eine Fiskal- oder Steuervertretung oder wollen Ihre Freizeit nicht mit buchhalterischen Fragen belasten?<a href=“#”>Mehr>></a>
      </p>
    </div>
```